# Run action when any screen interaction ends on a uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uibutton

At the moment I have 4 uiviews acting like a menu with another uiview above it acting as the menu reveal button which requires a long press to show the 4 uiviews. A user needs to long press on a uiview to show the uibuttons (menu) and then they would slide down over one of the uiview and then release the press. How can I tell which uiview the slide ended on.

Similar to how the 3D touch menus work.